# Convert id to Node in Gremlin Pipline

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, gremlin

I have node A that has an attribute which contains the value of another node B as the value of an attribute (FunctionId). There is no direct edge between A and B. What I want to do is select A and then move on to B depending on the value of A.functionId

Currently I get the node and the value of functionIdd like this

```
g.V[123].functionId
```

but how do I go on? Is there some pipeline-step that truns the integer value of functionId into a node?

```
g.V[123].functionId.the_magic.code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do:

```
g.v(123).functionId.transform{g.v(it)}
```

which would use the `transform` step to convert the value of `functionId` into a `Vertex` in the pipeline.